# Servidor MySql com Xampp para ser acessado por outra máquina?

Tags: mysql, aplicação-web, servidor, redes, xampp

eu sou um completo iniciante em mexer com programação Web e servidores locais e remotos, a minha noção sobre estes assuntos é bem parcial. Bom, eu tenho um sistema que precisará acessar um banco de dados Mysql. Porém este servidor com o banco de dados deverá estar em outra máquina, ou seja, preciso acessar remotamente a rede local de onde está o mysql com o xampp.

Pesquisei sobre o assunto em vários lugares, vários mesmo, e por saber realmente pouco sobre o assunto, acabei que me confundi cada vez mais. A minha dúvida é como eu posso criar e/ou configurar um servidor mysql com xampp para que eu possa acessa-lo remotamente? eu precisaria de uma outra rede isolada para as duas máquinas? Ou liberar o acesso online?

Desde já, agradeço a atenção de vocês.

Obs: Eu consigo acessar o banco via rede local da propria maquina utilizando o xampp, mas a intenção era prove o acesso via Ip para que eu possa acessa-lo via outra maquina.

Comment: XAMPP (Apache, MySQL, PHP e Perl, e o X é "cross platform") é uma coleção de programas. O MySQL que vem com ele é o mesmo que vem "solto" se baixar da página original. Se vai usar só o DB remotamente, não faz sentido instalar o XAMPP todo. Pegue só o MySQL, ou melhor ainda, o MariaDB, que é compatível, mas com um ciclo evolutivo melhor e mais aberto. Na verdade o XAMPP é uma maneira prática de montar um ambiente de testes, mas pra coisa séria, acho mais sensato instalar separadamente o MariaDB, o Apache e o PHP (e o Perl se precisar).

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pela resposta. Bom eu tenho instalado também o mysql da oracle com Workbench, com ele consegui acessar via rede local também. Porém no meu projeto o banco de dados será um intermediário entre o sistema e uma aplicação web. Achei que precisaria do xampp pra criar um servidor pra estes fins. Para tal, você não recomendaria o xampp?

Comment: Pela sua pergunta, da pra ver que você tá bem confuso sobre o que de fato é o tal XAMPP, mas vamos tentar ir direto ao ponto. Esse servidor onde ficará o MySQL, tem uma razão pra ele ser Windows? Você quer que seu sistema acesse o MySQL remotamente, portanto, a máquina onde ficará o MySQL precisa ter um IP fixo dentro da rede local e isso nos leva a segunda pergunta. Sua rede local possui algum roteador?

Comment: Os testes do sistema com o banco e a aplicação web serão para fins de apresentação mesmo, no caso o projeto seria meu tcc Por isso estou usando no windows mesmo. Possui roteador sim, é um Tp-link wr941nd, preciso liberar o acesso à porta 80 por ele?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem a tua pergunta, você quer que sua base de dados seja disponibilizada em outras maquinas. Sendo assim em uma rede local basta colocar o IP da maquina onde se encontra o xammp instalado.

Exemplo
192.168.1.100 <- IP da máquina onde esta instalado o xammp

192.168.1.100/phpmyadmin

Espero que seja isso que queria, qualquer coisa e só avisar !

Comment: Consegui conectar remotamente via rede local, porém consigo apenas o acesso pelo browser de outro dispositivo, ao acessar pelo ip na minha aplicação a conexao nao é estabelecida, mas sua resposta nao deixa de estar correta em relação a minha pergunta. Obrigado pela resposta.